# .net Datatable 1.10 API, statesave:true

Tags: javascript, .net, datatables

Hi I am trying to upgrade to  DataTables 1.10 API.

On the datatable I have changed from "bStatesave": true to "stateSave":true.

When I build with "stateSave":true, I dont see my changes but when I do "stateSave":false, I do see my change after I rebuild and navigate to my webpage.

I do need statesave to be true.

Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Using `"stateSave": true` is all you should need. Can you provide a minimal example, and describe a piece of state which is not being saved correctly?

Comment: You can also look in the local storage in your browser (F12 to open the dev tools), to see what state is actually being saved. The notes [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) may also help.